# Does r.js optimizer look at how javascript file is required from html when concatenating?

Tags: requirejs, amd, optimization

I'm trying to concatenate a 'common' library javascripts, and exlude those common files when concatenating individual apps.
(Idea presented here: http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project)

---

I have an `html` file which has

```
<script>

require("common"), function() {
  require(["some_app"], function(SomeApp) {
  });
});

</script>
```

---

`SomeApp.js` depends on some library files

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {
..
return SomeApp;
});
```

---

`common.js` include library files

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function() {});
```

---

my `build.js` for r.js optimizer looks like

```
{
  name: "SomeApp"
  exclude: ['common']  // intent: do not include common library files
}
```

When I run the optimizer, 'common' is indeed excluded from the concatenated SomeApp.js!
The result is exactly what I want, but I'm perplexed because r.js seems to inspect the html which requires javascript files.

Is it true? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result is exactly what I want, but I'm perplexed because r.js seems to inspect the html which requires javascript files.

`r.js` does not inspect HTML files. The result you describe getting is consistent with `r.js` operating purely on the JavaScript files and the build configuration you describe in your question.